# Vista SQL en Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me estoy conectando de Excel en la opcion donde dice Data,otras fuentes para ver una vista de SQL pero quiero mi lista se vea de forma desc y siempre que lo actualizo se ve asc que podria ocasionar eso? Aqui mi codigo

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT sales_order, customer, total_qty, total_por_ticket_qty, model, CONVERT(varchar, date_received, 6) AS Date_Received, CONVERT(varchar, due_date, 6) AS Due_Date, priority, categoria, 
                 CAST(Pz_por_hora AS decimal(11, 2)) AS Pz_por_Hora, CONVERT(varchar, cut, 6) AS Cut, CONVERT(varchar, sw630a830, 6) AS Sw630a830, CONVERT(varchar, sw830a1030, 6) AS Sw830a1030, CONVERT(varchar, sw1030a1230, 
                 6) AS Sw1030a1230, CONVERT(varchar, sw1230a230, 6) AS Sw1230a230, CONVERT(varchar, sw230a430, 6) AS Sw230a430, CONVERT(varchar, sw430a630, 6) AS Sw430a630, CONVERT(varchar, sewing_groupB, 6) 
                 AS Sewing_GroupB, CONVERT(varchar, inspection, 6) AS Inspection, CONVERT(varchar, ready_to_ship, 6) AS Ready_to_ship, shipped_date, shipping_containers, comments, CAST(points_unitarians AS decimal(11, 2)) 
                 AS Points_Unitarians, CAST(total_points AS decimal(11, 2)) AS Total_Points FROM dbo.tbl_Daily ORDER BY id_Daily DESC
```

Comment: ¿`dbo.tbl_Daily` es una vista o una tabla física?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es una tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El hecho de que order by no este permitido en las vistas, puede tener algo que ver, sin haber descendido al detalle de lo que planteas.

Es claro que has encontrado el "agujero" (top (100) percent..order by), para poder utilizar una ordenación en la propia vista, pero comunicarte con excel, es un tema diferente.

Mensaje 1033, nivel 15, estado 1, procedimiento VistaOrdenada, línea 30 [línea de inicio de lote 31]
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Lo que puedes hacer es aplicar el orden en el cliente Excel que consume los datos, y excluir el top order de la vista, para no penalizar el rendimiento. Siempre que refresques los datos, excel te mantendrá el orden que hayas dispuesto.